# Using CURL tool simulate HTTP request

Tags: http, curl

RT.

using curl simulate the following http request and print the response:

GET /\r\nHost: example.com\n

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following command will give you detailed header of request as well as response

```
 curl --request GET example.com -v
```